# Error while following kurento installation guide

Tags: updates

Im trying to install kurento in ubuntu 14.4 and in the middle of the installation guide (in sudo apt-get update command) an error occurs like

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.kurento.org/dists/trusty/InRelease Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Whats the cause of this error?. how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Note that Kurento Media Server (KMS) has to be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS **(64 bits)**

```
echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Try with the above method and then:

```
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server
```

I think it will resolve your issue.

Source:

http://builds.kurento.org/dev/master/latest/docs/installation_guide.html